# Mapping a domain name to Azure Linux VM App

Tags: linux, azure, dns, tomcat7

I followed the typical steps required for mapping my domain name to my Azure Linux Server application.
I bought the domain from a local service provider, now my issue is mapping that domain name to my cloud app.

I followed the steps on the following link, but still no result.
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/#access-app

I got the name servers for my DNS and applied it to the domain details, still no result.
**My application is just in the test phase and hasnt been moved to either staging or production environment. ** Is this by any chance the problem ?

Did I miss any steps, such as adding an End Point or creating a DNS server list ? etc ?

Kindly assist as I'm struggling with this for over 5 days now.

thanks in advance
Sai Krishna

Answer (score 2):

ok, so you must be having a DNS with you like

> yourdnsname.cloudapp.net

You should do the c-name based registration of your dns

create a C-Name record in domain management

> HOST - WWW 
>   Points to - yourdnsname.cloudapp.net

use the keep-alive time of standard 1 hr. it should just work.

Comment: We solved the problem
1) Configure CNAME, ANAME
2) ***Conifgure the end-point to listen to http-public and Tomcat-private key
2nd step is the KEY